# How to return the Max of a Sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have 2 Tables and in one of them (T) there's Sales for each transaction and in other Table (S) is state for each Transaction. the S.S is the Id which connects 2 tables.

What I have is

```sql
select sum(T.SALE_PRICE) as 'Sales of each state',S.STATE
  from T
  inner join S on T.S=S.S
  group by S.STATE
```

Which successfully returns the sum for each individual state. the difference between my question and other ones is that I need to join the tables to get the State and `Sum(T.SALE_PRICE)` which makes it hard.

How can I find out which state has the most sales?

Comment: Order by your aggregated column.

Comment: Is it possible to get it through a Subquery? i need only one State and one 'Sales of each state' @Larnu

Comment: @MostafaBouzari - it certainly is possible to do that via a subquery. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`

```
select TOP 1 sum(T.SALE_PRICE) as 'Sales of each state',S.STATE
FROM T
inner join S on T.S=S.S
group by S.STATE
ORDER BY sum(T.SALE_PRICE) DESC
```

Answer (score -3):

```sql
select MAX([Sales of each state]), STATE
FROM (
  select
    sum(T.SALE_PRICE) as 'Sales of each state',
    S.STATE
  from T
  inner join S on T.S = S.S
  group by S.STATE
) TEMP 
group by STATE
```

Comment: If you group by state, you will get one row **per state**.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?